# Bourbaki's definition of function

Tags: functions, logic, set-theory, foundations

I saw this definition and I got confused by it:

"Let E and F be two sets, which may or may not be distinct. A relation between a variable element x of E d a variable element y of F is called a functional relation in y if, for all x ∈ E, there exists a unique y ∈ F which is in the given relation with x. We give the name of function to the operation which in this way associates with every element x ∈ E the element y ∈ F which is in the given relation with x, and the function is said to be determined by the given functional relation. Two equivalent functional relations determine the same function."

The thing that confused me in the definition above was the sentence "We give the name of function to the operation which in this way associates with every element x ∈ E the element y ∈ F which is in the given relation with x..." (he didn't define the word "operation")

In 1954, Bourbaki defined a function as a triple f = (F, A, B). Here F is a functional graph, meaning a set of pairs where no two pairs have the same first member, and he hasn't used the term "operation" which he hasn't defined in the first definition.
my problem with this definition is the fact that it does not resemble the notion of function as a process...

My questions are:

1. why did he define in the first definition function as an operation (he didn't define what is an operation in the first place)?
2. where the notion of function as a process appear in any of those two definitions?

Thank you for your patience and time!

The definitions appear in the following links, paper, and book:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_function_concept

"Evolution of the Function Concept: A Brief Survey by
Israel Kleiner"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)

Nicolas Bourbaki - Set theory (book)

Comment: It is only an explanation... The definition states that a *relation* (math object previously defined) satisfying a *specific condition* (that of "functionality") is called a *function*. Fullstop

Comment: Who is "he"? Bourbaki was not "he".

Comment: No modern *definition* of function involves "the notion of function as a process". By 'modern' I mean, 20th C and on.  @AsafKaragila, Nicolas Bourbaki certainly isn't a she.

Comment: @BrianO: First of all, there is more than "he" and "she". Secondly, my point is that Bourbaki is a **they**, and not even a "singular they", but really a group of people.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sure, but it's a pleasant fiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some more context will help...

See [Elements of Mathematics: Theory of sets (Engl. transl.1968)](https://books.google.it/books?id=IL-SI67hjI4C&printsec=frontcover).

The "usual" mathematical object called *relation* in set theory is called by Bourbaki a *graph*, i.e. a set of *ordered pairs* [II.3.1].

A graph is said *functional* [II.3.4.: Def.9] when the "functionality" condition is satisfied.

What Bourbaki calls a *relation* is an expression of the language, i.e. an atomic formula based on a *predicate* symbols or a boolean combination, etc [see I.1.1, page 16 and Remark page 20: "intuitively terms represent *objects* and relations represent *assertions*"].

What is a *functional relation* (as defined in I.5.3)?

In a nutshell it is a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ satisfying the condition that:

> if $\varphi(x,y)$ and $\varphi(x,z)$, then $y=z$.

Thus, a *functional graph* is a mathematical object while a *functional relation* is a linguistic object.

---

Wiki's quote above is the English translation of the text of the first French edition: [Bourbaki (1939)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004H3BKYQ).

We can find into [Archives de l'Association des Collaborateurs de Nicolas Bourbaki](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/archives-bourbaki/PDF/048_iecnr_057.pdf) the corresponding "manuscript". See page 8:

> Soit $E$ et $F$ deux ensembles... Une *relation*...

If my conjecture is correct, the 2nd edition moved the "relation" name to the language of the theory and replaced it with "graph" and "correspondence" for the mathematical object.

Comment: Thank you!
I understood your point, but I have a question: I saw that relation is defined as the subset of A×B, but in the same book, N. Bourbaki defined relation to be an assembly that represents assertions. if so, then who of those definitions is the "correct" one?

Comment: I found another possible explanation for my question in Wikipedia: "Because relations arise in many scientific disciplines, as well as in many branches of mathematics and logic, there is considerable variation in terminology. Aside from the set-theoretic extension of a relational concept or term, the term "relation" can also be used to refer to the corresponding logical entity, either the logical comprehension, which is the totality of intensions or abstract properties shared by all elements in the relation, or else the symbols denoting these elements and intentions.

Comment: (in continuation to my comment above) Further, some writers of the latter persuasion introduce terms with more concrete connotations (such as "relational structure" for the set-theoretic extension of a given relational concept)".